# Как получить данные из HTML input использовать в ASP MVC их?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я знаю, что есть возможность сделать это с помощью `Request.Form.GetValues`

вот так выглядит view

```
  <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="searchString" type="text" id="searchString" class="form-control"/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" >Поиск</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Вот выглядит контроллер

```
var searchString = Request.Form.GetValues("searchString").FirstOrDefault();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    activeDirectory = activeDirectory.Where(a => a.DisplayName != null && a.DisplayName.Contains(searchString) 
                    || a.Company != null && a.Company.Contains(searchString));

                }
```

Но при запуске выпадает ошибка:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Значение не может быть неопределенным.

Как мне решить эту проблему? Загрузка данных идет ,через JSON мне нужно это сделать с помощью jquery.

Сейчас при запуске возникает ошибка скриншот 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данные можно достать по name из form, то есть если есть <input type="text" name="searchString"/> то можно передать строку как входной параметр метода

Answer (score 2):

Название свойства `Request.Form` сбивает с толку - на самом деле сюда попадают все значения, полученные из тела POST-запроса. Если вы делаете GET-запрос, либо POST-запрос, но передаете значение через строку запроса - то `Request.Form.GetValues("searchString")` будет пустым, отсюда и ошибка.

Проще всего принимать `searchString` как параметр действия (см. ответ Владимира) - тогда оно сможет быть получено из обоих источников.

Comment: А как же все таки с помощью Request.Form.GetValues получить данные ?

Comment: @shatoidil вы делаете правильно, ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: @shatoidil разве что я бы все же использовал индексатор Request.Form["searchString"]

Comment: Я приложил скриншот. Скорее я думаю не правильно ссылаюсь на этот инпут. Есть какие-то мысли поэтому ?

Comment: @shatoidil *прочитайте мои ответы еще раз*

Answer (score 1):

Параметры можно передавать так:

```
public void TestMethod(string searchString)
        {

        }


<form action="http://localhost:53013/Gameplay/TestMethod">
        <input name="searchString">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно без указания параметра `searchString` в методе достать значение через `Request.Params`, проверяя при этом, определена ли строка и не пустая ли она:

```
var searchString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["searchString"])
                 ? "" : Request.Params["searchString"];
```